Animated `points` in `polyline` (svg) seems to have a 512 limit/bug on iOS (not macOS)
I have an SVG with a single polyline inside.
On a desktop, android, macOS the animation works great.
The line starts drawing from the left side towards the right.
On iPadOS and iOS the animation starts to draw again from left towards the right, but the line appears broken into 3 segments. And all 3 segments start at the same time.
If I pick 512 points (or to say better 256 x,y pairs). The animation works correctly.
When I use more than 512 points I notice some corners are "broken"
And there are 3 starting points.
Note that length is always a positive number.
Tailwind animation
{
    keyframes: {
        drawLine: {
            from: {
                stroke-dashoffset": "var(--length)",
            },
            to: {
                "stroke-dashoffset": "0",
            },
        },
    },
    animation: {
        drawLine: "drawLine 5s linear forwards",
    }
}

className on the polyline:
className="stroke-escape-red stroke-2 fill-none animate-drawLine";

Polyline style:
style={{
    "--length": length,
    strokeMiterlimit: "10",
    strokeLineCap: "round",
    strokeLineJoin: "round",
    strokeDashoffset: length,
    strokeDasharray: length,
}}

Pictures:
polyline
broken corner
3 starting points
The length is extracted from .getTotalLength() function provided by the element


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body style="background-color: black">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1 {
            stroke: red;
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 2;
            animation: draw 5s linear forwards;
            stroke-dasharray: 8263.2890625;
            stroke-dashoffset: 8263.2890625;
          }
          @keyframes draw {
            0% {
              stroke-dashoffset: 8263.2890625;
            }
            100% {
              stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <polyline
        class="cls-1"
        points="0 523.1 112.9 523.1 115.2 509.8 121.3 542.3 124.4 526.1 230.5 526.1 230.5 455.6 261.4 455.6 261.4 434.1 283.1 434.1 283.1 444.8 272.7 444.8 272.7 466.7 261.4 466.7 261.4 510.4 283.1 510.4 283.1 455.3 294.3 455.3 294.3 423 250.8 423 250.8 444.4 239.7 444.4 239.7 423 218.1 423 218.1 413.1 207.5 413.1 207.5 400.5 218.1 400.5 218.1 390.5 185.2 390.5 185.2 379.2 206.7 379.2 206.7 346.5 141.4 346.5 141.4 313.3 163 313.3 163 324.2 152.7 324.2 152.7 335.9 195.8 335.9 195.8 302.6 228.9 302.6 228.9 335.9 240.2 335.9 240.2 346.5 228.3 346.5 228.3 368.5 250.8 368.5 250.8 346.5 261.4 346.5 261.4 357.3 283 357.3 283 303.4 294.6 303.4 294.6 292.2 305.5 292.2 305.5 312.3 315.6 312.3 315.6 324.4 338.2 324.4 338.2 292.2 393.2 292.2 393.2 248.9 414.6 248.9 414.6 292.2 425.5 292.2 425.5 313.3 414.6 313.3 414.6 346.1 403.7 346.1 403.7 357.8 392.4 357.8 392.4 368.5 381.5 368.5 381.5 346.1 360.1 346.1 360.1 368.5 283 368.5 283 413.1 294.3 413.1 293.8 378.4 326.6 378.4 326.6 399.5 316.3 399.5 316.3 390.3 305.5 390.3 305.5 423 327.5 423 327.5 444.8 316.3 444.8 316.3 477.5 337.4 477.5 337.9 410.8 348.5 410.8 348.5 423 381.7 423 381.7 390.5 403.7 390.5 403.7 423 447.7 423 447.7 411.6 490.9 411.6 490.9 433.6 523.7 433.6 523.7 444.9 490.9 444.9 490.9 477.6 467.4 477.6 467.4 466.4 447.3 466.4 447.3 499 479.8 499 479.8 510.6 436.5 510.6 436.5 455.8 425.5 455.8 425.5 467.4 415.1 467.4 415.1 489.9 370.8 489.9 370.8 468 359.8 468 359.8 521.1 283.6 521.1 283.6 533.9 273.2 533.9 273.2 543.7 293.6 543.7 293.6 576.3 304.8 576.3 304.8 543.7 315.5 543.7 315.5 554.9 327.1 554.9 327.1 532.4 349.1 532.4 349.1 564.6 370.8 564.6 370.8 521.1 403.8 521.1 403.8 500.6 415.1 500.6 415.1 509.6 426 509.6 426 554.7 414.9 554.7 414.9 565.2 436.2 565.2 436.2 521.1 656.9 521.1 659.2 507.8 665.3 540.3 668.4 524.1 880.5 524.2 880.5 499.9 891.3 499.9 891.3 521.1 913.3 521.1 913.3 468.3 901.9 468.3 901.9 423.6 967.4 423.6 967.4 390.5 989.1 390.5 989.1 368.6 1001 368.6 1001 346.7 1022.9 346.7 1022.9 412.3 1011.3 412.3 1011.3 423 1044.1 423 1044.1 390.6 1055.7 390.6 1055.7 433.6 1000.4 433.6 1000.4 477.4 979.1 477.4 979.1 465.8 967.4 465.8 967.4 433.6 945.8 433.6 945.8 444.9 935.5 444.9 935.5 455.5 945.8 455.5 945.8 509.6 966.6 509.6 966.6 500 999.8 500 999.8 532.1 1022 532.1 1022 468.6 1033.2 468.6 1033.2 488.6 1065.7 488.6 1065.7 454.9 1077.1 454.9 1077.1 433.6 1099.2 433.6 1099.2 445.5 1087.3 445.5 1087.3 466.7 1077.1 466.7 1077.1 485.5 1108.8 485.5 1108.8 467.4 1131.2 467.4 1131.2 478.6 1142.4 478.6 1142.4 488.6 1153.2 488.6 1153.2 510.6 1186.1 510.6 1186.1 564.9 1164.2 565.4 1164.2 532.6 1088.1 532.1 1088.1 521.4 1054.9 521.4 1054.9 587.1 1000.1 587.1 1000.1 630.7 977.6 630.7 977.6 619.6 968.2 619.6 968.2 587.1 956.6 587.1 956.6 608.6 945.5 608.6 945.5 663.7 934.4 663.7 934.4 707.4 880.5 707.4 880.5 718 1000.4 718 1000.4 805.2 1021.8 805.2 1021.8 838.7 1076.4 838.7 1076.4 816.7 1088.2 816.7 1088.2 860.6 1066.3 860.6 1066.3 892.8 1076.8 892.8 1076.8 882.1 1281.6 882.1 1283.9 868.8 1290 901.3 1293.1 885.1 1491.1 885.1 1491.1 893.1 1514.6 893.1 1514.6 904 1524.6 904 1524.6 882.1 1568.9 882.1 1568.9 838.7 1624 838.7 1624 882.1 1656.5 882.1 1656.5 849.2 1667.4 849.2 1667.4 892.6 1645.2 892.6 1645.2 904 1612.7 904 1612.7 915.3 1689.9 915.3 1689.9 926.5 1678.2 926.5 1678.2 936.4 1666.9 936.4 1666.9 969.7 1808.5 969.7 1808.5 950.4 1798.2 950.4 1798.2 934.5 1821.7 934.5 1821.7 946.2 1920 946.2"
      />
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>




Please post a svg example reproducing this error

@herrstrietzel I've updated my original post!
Thanks for taking a look!

Thanks! I see.  It is apparently a ios safari limitation. I also tried to scale the polyline - same result. As a workaround you may split your polyline in two and add a animation-delay to the second part. See codepen: https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/VwOvZgQ

I had tried splitting to multiple polylines but not paths, this indeed worked.
I've created a function to convert a single polyline to multiple paths, as I get those lines from the design dpt, and are quite a few.
Now I've got to solve a small issue, where the next path start leaves a "dot" showing.
Function here:
https://gist.github.com/stavros-k/ca179e150af84f011dfcd84df706cad4

Used on paths:
strokeDasharray: "100"
strokeDashoffset: "100"
and on keyframes:
drawLine: {
from: { "stroke-dashoffset": "100" },
to: { "stroke-dashoffset": "0" },
}
Works great now!
Thanks for the help!

Solution and codepen given by @herrstrietzel in the comments.
Basically, iOS seems to have a limitation, but you can work around it by splitting the polyline to multiple paths and delaying the animation on subsequent paths.


body {
  background-color: black;
}

.cls-1 {
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 0.2;
  animation: draw 5s linear forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 108">
  <path
      class="cls-1"
      pathLength="100"
      d="M0 52 11 52 12 51 12 54 12 53 23 53 23 46 26 46 26 43 28 43 28 44 27 44 27 47 26 47 26 51 28 51 28 46 29 46 29 42 25 42 25 44 24 44 24 42 22 42 22 41 21 41 21 40 22 40 22 39 19 39 19 38 21 38 21 35 14 35 14 31 16 31 16 32 15 32 15 34 20 34 20 30 23 30 23 34 24 34 24 35 23 35 23 37 25 37 25 35 26 35 26 36 28 36 28 30 29 30 29 29 31 29 31 31 32 31 32 32 34 32 34 29 39 29 39 25 41 25 41 29 43 29 43 31 41 31 41 35 40 35 40 36 39 36 39 37 38 37 38 35 36 35 36 37 28 37 28 41 29 41 29 38 33 38 33 40 32 40 32 39 31 39 31 42 33 42 33 44 32 44 32 48 34 48 34 41 35 41 35 42 38 42 38 39 40 39 40 42 45 42 45 41 49 41 49 43 52 43 52 44 49 44 49 48 47 48 47 47 45 47 45 50 48 50 48 51 44 51 44 46 43 46 43 47 42 47 42 49 37 49 37 47 36 47 36 52 28 52 28 53 27 53 27 54 29 54 29 58 30 58 30 54 32 54 32 55 33 55 33 53 35 53 35 56 37 56 37 52 40 52 40 50 42 50 42 51 43 51 43 55 41 55 41 57 44 57 44 52 66 52 66 51 67 54 67 52 88 52 88 50 89 50 89 52 91 52 91 47 90 47 90 42 97 42 97 39 99 39 99 37 100 37 100 35 102 35 102 41 101 41 101 42 104 42 104 39 106 39 106 43 100 43 100 48 98 48 98 47 97 47 97 43 95 43 95 44 94 44 94 46 95 46 95 51 97 51 97 50 100 50 100 53 102 53 102 47 103 47 103 49 107 49 107 45 "
      />

  <path
      style="animation-delay:5s"
      class="cls-1"
      pathLength="100"
      d="M108 45 108 43 110 43 110 45 109 45 109 47 108 47 108 49 111 49 111 47 113 47 113 48 114 48 114 49 115 49 115 51 119 51 119 56 116 57 116 53 109 53 109 52 105 52 105 59 100 59 100 63 98 63 98 62 97 62 97 59 96 59 96 61 95 61 95 66 93 66 93 71 88 71 88 72 100 72 100 81 102 81 102 84 108 84 108 82 109 82 109 86 107 86 107 89 108 89 108 88 128 88 128 87 129 90 129 89 149 89 149 89 151 89 151 90 152 90 152 88 157 88 157 84 162 84 162 88 166 88 166 85 167 85 167 89 165 89 165 90 161 90 161 92 169 92 169 93 168 93 168 94 167 94 167 97 181 97 181 95 180 95 180 93 182 93 182 95 192 95" />
</svg>



